# javascript property assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not sure why below is now working. Following is how the code is organized.

keys.js -- has all the keys, passwords
env.js -- switches the keys based on the environment (DEV,PROD etc) and assignes them to a ENV.KEYS property and then exports it for the rest of the app to use
db.js -- tries to use the MONGODB property but fails because the ENV.KEYS is undefined

As you can see from the output, I can get read in the keys.js in env,js -- but I am unable to assignment KEYS : keys.DEV based inside the switch statement is not working. I am not sure why.

Any help will be super helpful.

**keys.js**

```
const keys = {
  LOCAL: {
    GOOGLE: {
      CLIENT_ID: 'a1',
      CLIENT_SECRET: 'b1',
      CALLBACK_URL: 'c1'
    },
    MONGODB: {
      URI: 'd1'
    },
    COOKIE: {
      KEYS: ['e1', 'f1', 'g1']
    }
  },
  DEV: {
    GOOGLE: {
      CLIENT_ID: 'a2',
      CLIENT_SECRET: 'b2',
      CALLBACK_URL: 'c2'
    },
    MONGODB: {
      URI: 'd2'
    },
    COOKIE: {
      KEYS: ['e2', 'f2', 'g2']
    }
  },
  PROD: {
    GOOGLE: {
      CLIENT_ID: '',
      CLIENT_SECRET: '',
      CALLBACK_URL: ''
    },
    MONGODB: {
      URI: ''
    },
    COOKIE: {
      KEYS: []
    }
  }
};

module.exports = {
  keys
};
```

**env.js**

```
var keys = require('./keys');

var setEnv = function() {
  console.log(keys);
  console.log(keys.DEV);

  switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case 'LOCAL':
      return {
        KEYS: keys.LOCAL,
        PORT: process.env.PORT || 3000
      };

    case 'DEV':
      return {
        KEYS: keys.DEV,
        PORT: process.env.PORT || 3000
      };

    case 'PROD':
      return {
        KEYS: keys.PROD,
        PORT: process.env.PORT || 80
      };

    default:
      return {
        KEYS: keys.DEV,
        PORT: process.env.PORT || 3000
      };
  }
};

var ENV = setEnv();
console.log(ENV);

module.exports = {
  ENV
};
```

**db.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ENV = require('./env');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(ENV.KEYS.MONGODB.URI, {
  // useMongoClient: true
});

module.exports = {
  mongoose
};
```

When executed, i get ENV.KEYS as undefined.. What's am I doing wrong?

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
{ keys:
   { LOCAL: { GOOGLE: [Object], MONGODB: [Object], COOKIE: [Object] },
     DEV: { GOOGLE: [Object], MONGODB: [Object], COOKIE: [Object] },
     PROD: { GOOGLE: [Object], MONGODB: [Object], COOKIE: [Object] } } }
undefined
{ KEYS: undefined, PORT: 3000 }
C:\projects\test\server\config\db.js:5
mongoose.connect(ENV.KEYS.MONGODB.URI, {
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'MONGODB' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\test\server\config\db.js:5:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\test\server\server.js:10:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you export at keys.js you do,

```
module.exports = {
  keys
};
```

instead you should do,

```
module.exports = keys
```

Then it should work as you intended.

Comment: Thanks Skyler. That worked. I also needed to the same for the env.js